# Adding Canvas children in a for loop don't get displayed till loop is done

Tags: wpf, for-loop, children

What the tittle says, I have lengthy for loop in which based on some conditions I add objects to a Canvas. I want the objects to show as they are added but they show after the loop is done? Does anyone know why and how I can fix this?

**Also**: the textbox.text property doesn't get updated too.

Answer (score 0):

The UI won't update while you are tying up the UI thread, you need to return control to allow it to render.

You should try to move long-running operations to a background thread if possible - say using a `BackgroundWorker` - and update the UI every so often. This should result in a much more responsive UI.

If you *really* need to do some lengthy work on the UI thread (eg you're adding a large number of controls that are slow to render) you'll have to break it up into manageable portions. You can wait for the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event to know when the UI has rendered and you can continue. But it's much better to offload work to a background thread if you can.